# On Android device web-browser viewport is enormous relative to display. Why?

Tags: android, ios, browser

On an iOS device the browser - Safari - hosting my web-app properly fills the display. On an Android the - Chrome - browser is enormous relative to the screen, especially in landscape mode. This is true even on high res devices (2200 x 1400). How do I get consistent, properly sized browser viewport across all mobile devices?

Comment: WHat browser are you talking about?  There's dozens on Android.  Don't say "the default" as that differs by OEM and version.

Comment: Gabe, Chrome browser on Android.